# Number of solutions to $nx\equiv 0 \mod m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was reading an article about the number of group morphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m$ for $m,n>0$ and it turns out it's the same number of cosets $[x]\in\mathbb{Z}_m$ that satisfy $nx\equiv 0 \mod m$; it also said that the number of solutions is $ \gcd(m,n)$ but it didn't explain why. Any explanation to this?

Comment: The solutions are $x=\dfrac{km}{\gcd(m,n)}$ for $k=1$ to $\gcd(m,n)$